# Maximization to minimization with constraints

Tags: nonlinear-optimization

I have a maximization problem which is given below:

\begin{alignat}{2}
&\!\max_{x,y}        &\qquad& {x+2y}\\
&\text{subject to} &      & {x^2+y^2} = 1\\
&                  &      & 
\end{alignat}

And I need to convert it into a minimization problem. Here is what I think should be the solution:
\begin{alignat}{2}
&\!\min_{x,y}        &\qquad& {-x-2y}\\
&\text{subject to} &      & {-x^2-y^2} = -1\\
&                  &      & 
\end{alignat}
Does that sound right?

Comment: The constraints do not change, you just need to use that $\,\max(f) = -\min(-f)\,$.

Comment: Could you please lead me to the proof of your statement?

Comment: Just use the definitions, and $\,f \le M \iff -f \ge -M\,$.

Comment: Your problem seems to be $\max_x x+2\sqrt{1-x^2}$.   Use elementary calculus.

Comment: @herbsteinberg The problem statement does not expect me to solve the problem. It wants me to convert it into a standard minimization problem.

Comment: What is a "standard" minimization problem?  Is it one without constrains?

Comment: No. It is defined as one where the constraints are less than or equal to 0.